# Easiest way to get the absolute path of directory from browser

Tags: flash, applet

I allow my users to upload files from a directory. I use [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org) so that they can upload multiple files easily. However, I need to get the absolute path of the directory from which they are uploading.

A little research tells me that it can't be done in plain HTML/Javascript or in Flash.

Java applets seem to support this, so that's what I'm planning on using. I guess ActiveX can also do it, but I don't know much about ActiveX stuff, so I would rather avoid it.

Also, I can assume that the users are using Windows (XP or greater) and IE.

It there an easier way (other than writing a Java applet) that I'm missing? Having the user type in the directory into a textfield is an option, but not a very good one...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the path on the client computer?

Comment: Whenever you find yourselves needing to know the intricacies of client machines, it's time to pause and think again.

Comment: I need to replicate the directory structure (everything above where the users have selected files to upload) on the server. Hence, I need the full path of the directory. That's a requirement. No, I'm not writing a virus. And yes, I've thought about it (and I don't want to do it), but I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its cannot be done normally, and Java is not enabled by everyone

So, Put a extra textbox other than file upload box, and ask users to copy and paste the full path there.

PS: Thats really one of the option